# Less looping through array keeps appending previous value

Tags: css, loops, less, media-queries

I'm attempting to create generated spacing classes for my CSS.
I have a few embedded loops to create this, and inside my outer loop, I have my media queries defined. I have a set of inner styles that are being looped through and placed inside each of the 3 media queries.

For some reason, when the media queries are being looped through, it is adding the previous variable and appending 'and' for each media query, so my page looks like this:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {...}
@media (max-width: 991px) and (max-width: 767px) {...}
@media (max-width: 991px) and (max-width: 767px) and (max-width: 480px) {...}
```

When it should look like this:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {...}
@media (max-width: 767px) {...}
@media (max-width: 480px) {...}
```

I've added in other CSS properties in place of the `@media` to see if it was an issue with `@media`, but it still seems to duplicate in my loop. (FYI I'm using Less version **3.0**)

**Less**

```
@screen-xs-min: 480px;
@screen-sm-min: 768px;
@screen-md-min: 992px;
@screen-lg-min: 1200px;
@screen-xl-min: 1340px;

@screen-xs-max: (@screen-sm-min - 1);
@screen-sm-max: (@screen-md-min - 1);
@screen-md-max: (@screen-lg-min - 1);

@directionlist: l, b, r, t;
@directions: left, bottom, right, top;
@spacingtype: padding, margin;
@sapcingtypeabv: p, m;
@responsivevars: screen-xs-min, screen-xs-max, screen-sm-max;
@responsivevarsabv: xs, sm, md;

@maxg: 3;
.g-loop (@g) when (@g > 0) {

    @responsive: extract(@responsivevars, @g);
    @responsiveabv: extract(@responsivevarsabv, @g);

    @media (max-width: @@responsive) {

    @maxh: 2;
    .h-loop (@h) when (@h > 0) {

        @maxi: 50;
        .i-loop (@i) when (@i > -1) {

            @maxj: 4;
            .j-loop (@j) when (@j > 0) {

                @direction: extract(@directionlist, @j);
                @directionname: extract(@directions, @j);
                @type: extract(@spacingtype, @h);
                @typeabv: extract(@sapcingtypeabv, @h);

                .@{typeabv}-@{responsiveabv}-@{direction}-@{i} {
                    @{type}-@{directionname}: @i*1px !important;
                }

                .j-loop(@j - 1);
            }

            .j-loop (0) {}
            .j-loop(@maxj);

            .i-loop(@i - 5);
        }

        .i-loop (0) {}
        .i-loop(@maxi);
        .h-loop(@h - 1);
    }

    .h-loop (0) {}
    .h-loop(@maxh);
    .g-loop(@g - 1);
    } //Closing Media Query
}

.g-loop (0) {}
.g-loop(@maxg);
```

You can view a compiled result by using **[LESS Tester](https://lesstester.com/)**.

**Resulting CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .m-md-t-50 {
    margin-top: 50px !important;
  }
  .m-md-r-50 {
    margin-right: 50px !important;
  }
  .m-md-b-50 {
    margin-bottom: 50px !important;
  }
  .m-md-l-50 {
    margin-left: 50px !important;
  }
  .m-md-t-45 {
    margin-top: 45px !important;
  }
  .m-md-r-45 {
    margin-right: 45px !important;
  }
  .m-md-b-45 {
    margin-bottom: 45px !important;
  }
  .m-md-l-45 {
    margin-left: 45px !important;
  }
  .m-md-t-40 {
    margin-top: 40px !important;
  }
  .m-md-r-40 {
    margin-right: 40px !important;
  }
  .m-md-b-40 {
    margin-bottom: 40px !important;
  }
  .m-md-l-40 {
    margin-left: 40px !important;
  }
  .m-md-t-35 {
    margin-top: 35px !important;
  }
  .m-md-r-35 {
    margin-right: 35px !important;
  }
  .m-md-b-35 {
    margin-bottom: 35px !important;
  }
  .m-md-l-35 {
    margin-left: 35px !important;
  }
  .m-md-t-30 {
    margin-top: 30px !important;
  }
  .m-md-r-30 {
    margin-right: 30px !important;
  }
  .m-md-b-30 {
    margin-bottom: 30px !important;
  }
  .m-md-l-30 {
    margin-left: 30px !important;
  }
  .m-md-t-25 {
    margin-top: 25px !important;
  }
  .m-md-r-25 {
    margin-right: 25px !important;
  }
  .m-md-b-25 {
    margin-bottom: 25px !important;
  }
  .m-md-l-25 {
    margin-left: 25px !important;
  }
  .m-md-t-20 {
    margin-top: 20px !important;
  }
  .m-md-r-20 {
    margin-right: 20px !important;
  }
  .m-md-b-20 {
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  }
  .m-md-l-20 {
    margin-left: 20px !important;
  }
  .m-md-t-15 {
    margin-top: 15px !important;
  }
  .m-md-r-15 {
    margin-right: 15px !important;
  }
  .m-md-b-15 {
    margin-bottom: 15px !important;
  }
  .m-md-l-15 {
    margin-left: 15px !important;
  }
  .m-md-t-10 {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
  }
  .m-md-r-10 {
    margin-right: 10px !important;
  }
  .m-md-b-10 {
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  }
  .m-md-l-10 {
    margin-left: 10px !important;
  }
  .m-md-t-5 {
    margin-top: 5px !important;
  }
  .m-md-r-5 {
    margin-right: 5px !important;
  }
  .m-md-b-5 {
    margin-bottom: 5px !important;
  }
  .m-md-l-5 {
    margin-left: 5px !important;
  }
  .m-md-t-0 {
    margin-top: 0px !important;
  }
  .m-md-r-0 {
    margin-right: 0px !important;
  }
  .m-md-b-0 {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  }
  .m-md-l-0 {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
  }
  .p-md-t-50 {
    padding-top: 50px !important;
  }
  .p-md-r-50 {
    padding-right: 50px !important;
  }
  .p-md-b-50 {
    padding-bottom: 50px !important;
  }
  .p-md-l-50 {
    padding-left: 50px !important;
  }
  .p-md-t-45 {
    padding-top: 45px !important;
  }
  .p-md-r-45 {
    padding-right: 45px !important;
  }
  .p-md-b-45 {
    padding-bottom: 45px !important;
  }
  .p-md-l-45 {
    padding-left: 45px !important;
  }
  .p-md-t-40 {
    padding-top: 40px !important;
  }
  .p-md-r-40 {
    padding-right: 40px !important;
  }
  .p-md-b-40 {
    padding-bottom: 40px !important;
  }
  .p-md-l-40 {
    padding-left: 40px !important;
  }
  .p-md-t-35 {
    padding-top: 35px !important;
  }
  .p-md-r-35 {
    padding-right: 35px !important;
  }
  .p-md-b-35 {
    padding-bottom: 35px !important;
  }
  .p-md-l-35 {
    padding-left: 35px !important;
  }
  .p-md-t-30 {
    padding-top: 30px !important;
  }
  .p-md-r-30 {
    padding-right: 30px !important;
  }
  .p-md-b-30 {
    padding-bottom: 30px !important;
  }
  .p-md-l-30 {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
  }
  .p-md-t-25 {
    padding-top: 25px !important;
  }
  .p-md-r-25 {
    padding-right: 25px !important;
  }
  .p-md-b-25 {
    padding-bottom: 25px !important;
  }
  .p-md-l-25 {
    padding-left: 25px !important;
  }
  .p-md-t-20 {
    padding-top: 20px !important;
  }
  .p-md-r-20 {
    padding-right: 20px !important;
  }
  .p-md-b-20 {
    padding-bottom: 20px !important;
  }
  .p-md-l-20 {
    padding-left: 20px !important;
  }
  .p-md-t-15 {
    padding-top: 15px !important;
  }
  .p-md-r-15 {
    padding-right: 15px !important;
  }
  .p-md-b-15 {
    padding-bottom: 15px !important;
  }
  .p-md-l-15 {
    padding-left: 15px !important;
  }
  .p-md-t-10 {
    padding-top: 10px !important;
  }
  .p-md-r-10 {
    padding-right: 10px !important;
  }
  .p-md-b-10 {
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
  }
  .p-md-l-10 {
    padding-left: 10px !important;
  }
  .p-md-t-5 {
    padding-top: 5px !important;
  }
  .p-md-r-5 {
    padding-right: 5px !important;
  }
  .p-md-b-5 {
    padding-bottom: 5px !important;
  }
  .p-md-l-5 {
    padding-left: 5px !important;
  }
  .p-md-t-0 {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
  }
  .p-md-r-0 {
    padding-right: 0px !important;
  }
  .p-md-b-0 {
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  }
  .p-md-l-0 {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .m-sm-t-50 {
    margin-top: 50px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-r-50 {
    margin-right: 50px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-b-50 {
    margin-bottom: 50px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-l-50 {
    margin-left: 50px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-t-45 {
    margin-top: 45px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-r-45 {
    margin-right: 45px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-b-45 {
    margin-bottom: 45px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-l-45 {
    margin-left: 45px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-t-40 {
    margin-top: 40px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-r-40 {
    margin-right: 40px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-b-40 {
    margin-bottom: 40px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-l-40 {
    margin-left: 40px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-t-35 {
    margin-top: 35px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-r-35 {
    margin-right: 35px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-b-35 {
    margin-bottom: 35px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-l-35 {
    margin-left: 35px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-t-30 {
    margin-top: 30px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-r-30 {
    margin-right: 30px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-b-30 {
    margin-bottom: 30px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-l-30 {
    margin-left: 30px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-t-25 {
    margin-top: 25px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-r-25 {
    margin-right: 25px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-b-25 {
    margin-bottom: 25px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-l-25 {
    margin-left: 25px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-t-20 {
    margin-top: 20px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-r-20 {
    margin-right: 20px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-b-20 {
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-l-20 {
    margin-left: 20px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-t-15 {
    margin-top: 15px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-r-15 {
    margin-right: 15px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-b-15 {
    margin-bottom: 15px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-l-15 {
    margin-left: 15px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-t-10 {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-r-10 {
    margin-right: 10px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-b-10 {
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-l-10 {
    margin-left: 10px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-t-5 {
    margin-top: 5px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-r-5 {
    margin-right: 5px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-b-5 {
    margin-bottom: 5px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-l-5 {
    margin-left: 5px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-t-0 {
    margin-top: 0px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-r-0 {
    margin-right: 0px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-b-0 {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  }
  .m-sm-l-0 {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-t-50 {
    padding-top: 50px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-r-50 {
    padding-right: 50px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-b-50 {
    padding-bottom: 50px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-l-50 {
    padding-left: 50px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-t-45 {
    padding-top: 45px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-r-45 {
    padding-right: 45px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-b-45 {
    padding-bottom: 45px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-l-45 {
    padding-left: 45px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-t-40 {
    padding-top: 40px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-r-40 {
    padding-right: 40px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-b-40 {
    padding-bottom: 40px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-l-40 {
    padding-left: 40px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-t-35 {
    padding-top: 35px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-r-35 {
    padding-right: 35px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-b-35 {
    padding-bottom: 35px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-l-35 {
    padding-left: 35px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-t-30 {
    padding-top: 30px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-r-30 {
    padding-right: 30px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-b-30 {
    padding-bottom: 30px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-l-30 {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-t-25 {
    padding-top: 25px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-r-25 {
    padding-right: 25px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-b-25 {
    padding-bottom: 25px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-l-25 {
    padding-left: 25px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-t-20 {
    padding-top: 20px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-r-20 {
    padding-right: 20px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-b-20 {
    padding-bottom: 20px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-l-20 {
    padding-left: 20px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-t-15 {
    padding-top: 15px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-r-15 {
    padding-right: 15px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-b-15 {
    padding-bottom: 15px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-l-15 {
    padding-left: 15px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-t-10 {
    padding-top: 10px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-r-10 {
    padding-right: 10px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-b-10 {
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-l-10 {
    padding-left: 10px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-t-5 {
    padding-top: 5px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-r-5 {
    padding-right: 5px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-b-5 {
    padding-bottom: 5px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-l-5 {
    padding-left: 5px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-t-0 {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-r-0 {
    padding-right: 0px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-b-0 {
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  }
  .p-sm-l-0 {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) and (max-width: 767px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .m-xs-t-50 {
    margin-top: 50px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-r-50 {
    margin-right: 50px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-b-50 {
    margin-bottom: 50px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-l-50 {
    margin-left: 50px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-t-45 {
    margin-top: 45px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-r-45 {
    margin-right: 45px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-b-45 {
    margin-bottom: 45px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-l-45 {
    margin-left: 45px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-t-40 {
    margin-top: 40px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-r-40 {
    margin-right: 40px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-b-40 {
    margin-bottom: 40px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-l-40 {
    margin-left: 40px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-t-35 {
    margin-top: 35px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-r-35 {
    margin-right: 35px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-b-35 {
    margin-bottom: 35px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-l-35 {
    margin-left: 35px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-t-30 {
    margin-top: 30px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-r-30 {
    margin-right: 30px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-b-30 {
    margin-bottom: 30px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-l-30 {
    margin-left: 30px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-t-25 {
    margin-top: 25px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-r-25 {
    margin-right: 25px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-b-25 {
    margin-bottom: 25px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-l-25 {
    margin-left: 25px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-t-20 {
    margin-top: 20px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-r-20 {
    margin-right: 20px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-b-20 {
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-l-20 {
    margin-left: 20px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-t-15 {
    margin-top: 15px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-r-15 {
    margin-right: 15px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-b-15 {
    margin-bottom: 15px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-l-15 {
    margin-left: 15px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-t-10 {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-r-10 {
    margin-right: 10px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-b-10 {
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-l-10 {
    margin-left: 10px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-t-5 {
    margin-top: 5px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-r-5 {
    margin-right: 5px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-b-5 {
    margin-bottom: 5px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-l-5 {
    margin-left: 5px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-t-0 {
    margin-top: 0px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-r-0 {
    margin-right: 0px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-b-0 {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  }
  .m-xs-l-0 {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-t-50 {
    padding-top: 50px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-r-50 {
    padding-right: 50px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-b-50 {
    padding-bottom: 50px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-l-50 {
    padding-left: 50px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-t-45 {
    padding-top: 45px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-r-45 {
    padding-right: 45px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-b-45 {
    padding-bottom: 45px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-l-45 {
    padding-left: 45px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-t-40 {
    padding-top: 40px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-r-40 {
    padding-right: 40px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-b-40 {
    padding-bottom: 40px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-l-40 {
    padding-left: 40px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-t-35 {
    padding-top: 35px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-r-35 {
    padding-right: 35px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-b-35 {
    padding-bottom: 35px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-l-35 {
    padding-left: 35px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-t-30 {
    padding-top: 30px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-r-30 {
    padding-right: 30px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-b-30 {
    padding-bottom: 30px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-l-30 {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-t-25 {
    padding-top: 25px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-r-25 {
    padding-right: 25px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-b-25 {
    padding-bottom: 25px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-l-25 {
    padding-left: 25px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-t-20 {
    padding-top: 20px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-r-20 {
    padding-right: 20px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-b-20 {
    padding-bottom: 20px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-l-20 {
    padding-left: 20px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-t-15 {
    padding-top: 15px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-r-15 {
    padding-right: 15px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-b-15 {
    padding-bottom: 15px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-l-15 {
    padding-left: 15px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-t-10 {
    padding-top: 10px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-r-10 {
    padding-right: 10px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-b-10 {
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-l-10 {
    padding-left: 10px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-t-5 {
    padding-top: 5px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-r-5 {
    padding-right: 5px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-b-5 {
    padding-bottom: 5px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-l-5 {
    padding-left: 5px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-t-0 {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-r-0 {
    padding-right: 0px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-b-0 {
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  }
  .p-xs-l-0 {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
  }
}
```

This is my first time using Less logic heavily, so please let me know if there is a better way of doing things.

Comment: So it's just concatenating your media queries, I can't read thru the code, too many loops but it seems like you can simplify the looping a bit by separating them into each media query then calling the loop you need

Comment: @Huangism Thank you for the comment. Yeah, it is a lot, haha. If I were to just write out the media queries and then call the loops, would I still be able to have the loops embedded within each other when I call them? Because they're all dependent on one another.

Comment: I think it should as long as it is built properly. `@media (max-width: @@responsive) {` this line seems to be the issue and you are only looping it 3 times outputting that line. So separating it out and passing in the correct parameter should resolve the issue. Sometimes it is better to do one thing at a time then try to fit everything in one. Specially when you look at this later when you have no idea what it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary suggestion:

#### Use [`each`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-each) function instead.

Since you're using Less *3.x* anyway (and then there's no real reason to not upgrade to *3.7* as there's no hard-breaking changes between 3.* versions) - there's no reason to bother with recursive mixins for trivial loops. Recursive mixin loops remain useful only to generate "recursive values", i.e. when each new iteration needs to reuse a value generated by prev. iteration - it's something `each` can't do.

---

Either way let's see what's wrong with your example - just for the reference.

Your key mistake is that you put your "next-iteration-call" for media queries (i.e. `.g-loop(@g - 1);`) in wrong place. Basically you put it *inside* the media query block while it should be *outside* of it. So it's not a surprise they get nested into each other in the result.
Let's start from a simplified example (just a single-level loop implemented the same way):

```
.outer-iter(@i) when (@i > 0) {
    block {
        .outer-iter(@i - 1);
        itick: @i;
    }
}

.outer-iter(3);
```

This will generate something like:

```css
block {
  itick: 3;
}
block block {
  itick: 2;
}
block block block {
  itick: 1;
}
```

exactly because each new `block` is generated inside of the previous one.
The proper loop code in this case would be:

```
.outer-iter(@i) when (@i > 0) {
    .outer-iter(@i - 1);
    block {
        itick: @i;
    }
}
```

---

There're a few more cosmetic mistakes (not quite hurting errors but still) that suggest you used some stone age tutorial (~6 years old or so). Briefly:

- use of `.*-loop (0) {}` terminals - this is not necessary for a while (just a noise)
- hardcoded n-iteration values - you'll have to find and fix them each time your data changes. Use `length` function instead.

---

Well, I won't bother you with other cosmetic problems (yes, there're a few more), let's just stop with (sort of) **fixed code**:

```
...

@max-pm-size: 50;

.g-loop(@g) when (@g > 0) {

    @responsive: extract(@responsivevars, @g);
    @responsiveabv: extract(@responsivevarsabv, @g);

    @media (max-width: @@responsive) {

        .h-loop(@h) when (@h > 0) {

            .i-loop(@i) when (@i > -1) {

                .j-loop(@j) when (@j > 0) {
                    @direction: extract(@directionlist, @j);
                    @directionname: extract(@directions, @j);
                    @type: extract(@spacingtype, @h);
                    @typeabv: extract(@sapcingtypeabv, @h);

                    .@{typeabv}-@{responsiveabv}-@{direction}-@{i} {
                        @{type}-@{directionname}: @i*1px !important; /* each time you use !important a kitty dies */
                    }

                    .j-loop(@j - 1);
                }

                .j-loop(length(@directions));
                .i-loop(@i - 5);
            }

            .i-loop(@max-pm-size);
            .h-loop(@h - 1);
        }

        .h-loop(length(@spacingtype));

    } // ~ end of @media

    .g-loop(@g - 1); // <- this was your key mistake
}

.g-loop(length(@responsivevars));
```

Comment: Technically there **is** another much critical problem you may face if you keep implementing nested loops by *defining* inner loop bodies inside outer loop bodies. So as suggested in comment above it's also good idea to separate loop bodies (you don't even need to pass variables from one to another -  a body of the called mixin *can see* (and use) its calling scope variable). But since this particular code does not (fortunately, for several reasons) really suffer from this  "nested-loop-bodies" issue I did not even mentioned it in the answer (it's a huge and complecated issue of its own).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for the suggestions! I'm pretty new with the LESS functionality so your points are very much appreciated.